# check if all dictionary values with keys starting with a given string exist in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

The current way I have it coded is not working as "all" is returning false because while looping the key.startswith() is flagging as false during iterations over the non desired keys.

Essentially what I want is to check if all the keys prefixed by the passed string have a value. I wanted to try to do it one line for my own challenge (not that it's necessarily better to do so) but feeling stuck. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
class MyPlayer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_attributes = {
        "one_height": "5'8",
        "one_weight": "150",
        "one_age": "25",
        "two_height": "5'11",
        "two_weight": "160",
        "two_age": None, 
        }
    def check_if_all_values_exist(self, prefix_to_check):
        if all([key.startswith(prefix_to_check) and self.player_attributes[key] != None for key in self.player_attributes.keys()]):
            print("true")

Test = MyPlayer()
Test.check_if_all_values_exist("one")
Test.check_if_all_values_exist("two")
```

Comment: `if all([key.startswith(prefix_to_check) and self.player_attributes[key] != None for key in self.player_attributes.keys()]):` This means: for all the keys, you will check that the key starts with the prefix and has a non-None value. What you wanted was: for all the keys, *if* it starts with the prefix, it has a non-None value. Or in other words: for all the keys, the key has a non-None value *or* it does *not* start with the prefix. Do you understand why this is logically equivalent? Knowing this, can you write the code?

Comment: How to think about it: When you try to solve problems iterating over lists, it's important to think about what you want to do at the individual element level. If you're doing an `all` check, you need to think of the condition that should be true for a given element. What's allowed and what isn't allowed? Clearly, it doesn't *have* to start with the prefix. What should be true if it does start with the prefix? If it doesn't, are there any other restrictions? When I asked myself those questions, I came up with the rule in the other comment.

Comment: `return all(v != None for k,v in player_attributes.items() if k.startswith(x))`

Comment: Right; another way to do it is to filter which keys are considered by `all`. That's better, actually.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks! I got it working by changing the if statement to `if all([key.startswith(prefix_to_check) == False or self.player_attributes[key] != None for key in self.player_attributes.keys()]):` The other solutions posted seem better than mine so I'll try to learn from those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring all the class and other parts and looking at only the function, here's the one liner for you.

```
return all(v != None for k,v in player_attributes.items() if k.startswith(x))
```

Always remember to filter out the noise so you can just focus on what's really needed. Then it becomes easy for you to decide if you are getting the result you need or not. In the loop above, the for loop is filtering out all keys if they don't start with `prefix_to_check`. Then it becomes easy to see if `value` is `None` or not.

The full function definition will be:

```
def check_key(x):
    player_attributes = {
    "one_height": "5'8",    
    "one_weight": "150",
    "one_age": "25",
    "two_height": "5'11",
    "two_weight": "160",
    "two_age": None, 
    }

    return all(v != None for k,v in player_attributes.items() if k.startswith(x))

print ('one', check_key('one'))
print ('two', check_key('two'))
```

Output:

```
one, True
two, False
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to think more carefully through your condition: you're in trouble *only* when a key *does* begin with the tagged string, *and* it has no value (aka is None).  The you need to apply DeMorgan's theorem.  I've coded this more usably to return a Boolean value, but I preserved the `print` aspect to trace the results.

```
...
    def check_if_all_values_exist(self, prefix_to_check):
        result = all([not key.startswith(prefix_to_check) or
                      self.player_attributes[key] != None
                for key in self.player_attributes.keys()])
        print(prefix_to_check, result)

Test = MyPlayer()
Test.check_if_all_values_exist("one")
Test.check_if_all_values_exist("two")
```

Output:

```
one True
two False
```